# Output video on host in VLC

Tags: ssh, video

I have a server with VLC installed and a graphics card.

I have access to the server in person and can play videos while logged in locally, but I want to able to launch a VLC instance remotely through SSH and have it run on the server and output everything on the server as well.

Audio is no problem as that by default uses the localhost audio server, but the video wants to pipe itself over ssh to my console, I want to be able to run this video out to the local screen connected to the server.

Comment: I may be missing something here, but why are you watching videos on a server?

Comment: just a general how do I do this, also because I want to be able to control my TV both from the console and the remote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your DISPLAY variable to the correct local XServer.
ie. Make it the same as the local session

Answer (score 0):

In bash:

export DISPLAY=:0